# Awk via ssh with variable

Tags: bash, awk, ssh

HI I`m trying to execute something like this:

```
ssh USER@SERVER 'command=`ps -aux | grep xyz | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $11}'` && echo $command'
```

and I get

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Is there any way to get it working?

Please, help me! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `grep xyz | grep -v grep | awk '{...}'` is more simply expressed as `awk '/[x]yz/{...}'`

Answer (score 3):

## Simpler command

Try:

```
ssh USER@SERVER 'ps -p "$(pgrep -d, xyz)" -o comm='
```

#### Notes

1. `-p "$(pgrep -d, xyz)"` selects for commands whose names include the string `xyz`.
2. `-o comm=` selects the output format that you want.

## Quoting and the original command

Instead of the original command, try:

```
ssh USER@SERVER 'command=`ps -aux | grep xpdf | grep -v grep | awk '\''{ print $11}'\''` && echo $command'
```

Observe, that inside quoted command string, `'` has been replaced with `'\''`.

#### Discussion

This is not one single-quoted string:

```
'command=`ps -aux | grep xyz | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $11}'` && echo $command'
```

It consists of the following:

1. A single quoted string:

   ```
   'command=`ps -aux | grep xyz | grep -v grep | awk '
   ```
2. An unquoted string:

   ```
   { print $11}
   ```
3. A single-quoted string:

   ```
   '` && echo $command'
   ```

There is no way to put single-quotes *inside* single quoted strings.  One has to end the first single-quoted string with a closing single-quote, follow it with an escaped single-quote, and follow this with a single-quote to  open a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch that's confusing here.  First:  you can restructure your remote command entirely within awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { cmd="ps aux"; while( (cmd | getline) >0) {if($0 ~ /xyz/) print $11}}'
```

If you happen to know which field you expect "xyz" to occur in, you can test that directly and eliminate your negative test (which I've omitted above).  We can add that back if you insist:

```
awk 'BEGIN { cmd="ps xyz"; while( (cmd | getline) >0) {if($0 ~ /xyz/ && $0 !~ /awk/) print $11}}'
```

But say I'm interested in what user `clamav` is up to:

```
awk 'BEGIN { cmd="ps aux"; while( (cmd | getline) >0) {if($1 ~ /clamav/) print $11}}'
```

Another issue is that you're *defining* and *echoing* an environment variable remotely, which introduces a bunch of complications.  Why not exploit `SendEnv` instead.  Generally this is `LANG LC_*`, but the latter is liberal as to what it allows:

```
export LC_command="awk 'BEGIN { cmd=\"ps aux\"; while( (cmd | getline) >0) {if($1 ~ /clamav/) print $11}}'"
ssh -o USER@HOST 'echo $LC_command'
```

Other options include providing a script or shell function which can be executed remotely, which avoids a lot of SSH & shell quote fumbling.

Any more clarification on what you're hoping to accomplish?

Comment: That will spin off into an infinite loop if the `getline` fails.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  If getline has no output, the while loop terminates.  The awk script terminates on no output.  If ps produces an infinite list of processes, I'd suggest you've other problems.

Comment: Any kind of shell problem in the call to cmd. Given a failure, getline returns `-1` which is non-zero and so `while (cmd|getline)` will continue looping and, presumably, failing. The correct syntax for calling getline is `while ( (cmd|getline) > 0 )`.

Comment: How might getline return a -1?  I've checked against, say, 'cmd="false"' and 'cmd="notacommand"', and both terminate:  awk 'BEGIN { cmd="notacommand"; while( cmd | getline) print i++; }'

Comment: The good thing about programming defensively is that you don't have to care what might cause the failure, it's enough to know that it CAN fail (because the providers TELL you it can) and how to code to handle it. Having said that - maybe the shell running out of resources to fork processes or create pipes or the command the pipe is coming from gets killed or....

Comment: You can many of the possible values of ERRNO (which GNU awk getline can populate) at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html. Only a small subset will apply to getline failures and I neither know nor care which those are but it might give you some ideas if you want to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks again.  Agreed absolutely on defensive programming.  I try to practice that, so long as I'm aware of what to defend against.